# Не происходит рендера элемента, хотя он отображается

Tags: reactjs, redux, render

У меня есть выпадающий список с контейнером DropDown. В контейнере есть Group`ы. Элемент DroupDown рендерится когда меняется глобальный state и с сервера приходят необходимые данные:

```
const groupsWithData = useSelector(store => { return store.persons.structurePersons })
      useEffect(() => {
          if (groupsWithData) {
              setGroupElem(groupsWithData.map((item) => {
                  return <Group 
                  key={item.group_id} 
                  groupName={item.group_name} 
                  idGroup={item.group_id} 
                  positionData={item.group_data} 
                  isOpen={item.group_isOpen}
                  handleToggleVisibleGroup={handleToggleVisibleGroup}
                  />
              }))
            }          
      },[groupsWithData])
```

При этом в элемент Group передается много всего. Group - это тоже элемент со вложенными элементами. Помимо данных из State в Group передается ф-ия `handleToggleVisibleGroup`, которая должна менять признак открыта ли группа или закрыта по клику на Group. Что происходит у меня - у меня рендерится DropDown и, как я предполагал, рендерятся все Group, так как я могу развернуть DropDown и увидеть все вложенные Groups, согласно глобальному State... Я запускаю ф-ию

```
handleToggleVisibleGroup по клику на Group. 
    const handleToggleVisibleGroup = (groupId) => {
        dispatch(toggleVisiblePosition(groupId))
    }
```

У меня срабатывает редьюсер и в State меняются данные согласно задуманному... НО перерендера не происходит... посмотрел на данные и девтул и удивился... Group вообще не рендерится... я не понимаю, что происходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь компонент DropDown:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './DropDown.css'
import Group from "../Group/Group";
import Button from "../Button/Button";

import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { toggleVisiblePosition } from '../../redux/actions';

const DropDown = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [isVisibleDopDown, setIsVisibleDropDown] = useState(false)
    const [groupElem, setGroupElem] = useState(<Group/>)

    const groupsWithData = useSelector(store => { return store.persons.structurePersons })

    const handleToggleVisibleGroup = (groupId) => {
        dispatch(toggleVisiblePosition(groupId))
    }

      useEffect(() => {
          if (groupsWithData) {
              setGroupElem(groupsWithData.map((item) => {
                  return <Group 
                  key={item.group_id} 
                  groupName={item.group_name} 
                  idGroup={item.group_id} 
                  positionData={item.group_data} 
                  isOpen={item.group_isOpen}
                  handleToggleVisibleGroup={handleToggleVisibleGroup}
                  />
              }))
            }          
      },[groupsWithData])


    const toggleVisibleDropDown = (e) => {
        setIsVisibleDropDown(!isVisibleDopDown)
    }

    return (
        <div className="drop-down">
            <Button
                handleClick={toggleVisibleDropDown}
                cusStyle={`button button_drop-down-menu ${isVisibleDopDown === true ? 'button_drop-down-menu_visible' : ''}`}
                text={'Сотрудники'}
            />
            <ul className={`drop-down__container ${isVisibleDopDown === true ? 'drop-down__container_visible' : ''}`}>
                {groupElem}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DropDown;
```

Компонент Group

```
import './Group.css'
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "../Checkbox/Checkbox";
import Position from "../Position/Position";
import arrow from "../../img/arrow.png";
import uniq from 'uniqid';


const Group = ({ groupName, positionData, idGroup, isOpen, handleToggleVisibleGroup }) => {

    return (
        <li onClick={() => handleToggleVisibleGroup(idGroup)} className="group">
            <div className="group__header">
                <Checkbox label={groupName} />
                <img className="group__header-img" src={arrow} alt="" />
            </div>
            <ul className={`group__items-list ${isOpen === true ? 'group__items-list_visible' : ''}`}>
                {
                    positionData.map((item) => {
                        const keyId = uniq()
                        return <Position
                            id={keyId}
                            key={keyId}
                            label={item.position_name}
                            persons={item.persons}
                        />
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </li>
    )
}

export default Group;
```

Так же добавил то, как отображается state. Видно, что при клике по Group свойство group_isOpen стало true, но отобразится это только после того, как я закрою и открою заново DropDown

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код редьюсера:

```
import personsUtils from '../utils/personsUtils';
import { GET_ALL_PERSONS, TOGGLE_VISIBLE_POSITION } from "./types"


const initialState = {
    mainStatePersons: [],
    structurePersons: []
}

export const persons = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_ALL_PERSONS:
        const persons = personsUtils.setId(action.allPersons)
        const positions = personsUtils.getPositionsPerson(persons);
        return {
            ...state,
            mainStatePersons: persons,
            structurePersons: positions
        }
        
        case TOGGLE_VISIBLE_POSITION:
        state.structurePersons.some((item) => {
            if (item.group_id === action.id) {
                item.group_isOpen = !item.group_isOpen;
                return true
            }
            return false
        })
        return {
            ...state
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Весь компонент прикрепите. Кроме этого, у вас есть источник данных - `groupsWithData`,  зачем нужен `setGroupElem`? Зачем здесь `useEffect`?

Comment: Прикрпепил DropDown компонент. Использую useEffect, т.к. если убираю появляется ошибка too many rerenders

Comment: Нужен код редьюсера. Похоже, что массив persons.structurePersons мутируется, а не создается новый. Т.к. массив тот же, то перерисовка не происходит

Comment: Добавил код редьюсера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас уже есть источник данных, ваш стор redux'а, дополнительно к этому наращивать `useState` нет никакого смысла.
См. комментарии ниже.

p.s.Для формирования списка имен классов используйте библиотеку [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./DropDown.css";
import Group from "../Group/Group";
import Button from "../Button/Button";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { toggleVisiblePosition } from "../../redux/actions";

const DropDown = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  //получили данные
  const groupsWithData = useSelector((store) => {
    return store.persons.structurePersons;
  });

  const [isVisibleDopDown, setIsVisibleDropDown] = useState(false);
  //const [groupElem, setGroupElem] = useState(<Group />) зачем оно здесь?;

  const handleToggleVisibleGroup = (groupId) => {
    dispatch(toggleVisiblePosition(groupId));
  };

  /*
  не нужен
  useEffect(() => {
    if (groupsWithData) {
      setGroupElem(
        groupsWithData.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Group
              key={item.group_id}
              groupName={item.group_name}
              idGroup={item.group_id}
              positionData={item.group_data}
              isOpen={item.group_isOpen}
              handleToggleVisibleGroup={handleToggleVisibleGroup}
            />
          );
        })
      );
    }
  }, [groupsWithData]);*/

  const toggleVisibleDropDown = (e) => {
    setIsVisibleDropDown(!isVisibleDopDown);
  };

  return (
    <div className="drop-down">
      <Button
        handleClick={toggleVisibleDropDown}
        cusStyle={`button button_drop-down-menu ${
          isVisibleDopDown === true ? "button_drop-down-menu_visible" : ""
        }`} 
        text={"Сотрудники"}
      />
      <ul
        className={`drop-down__container ${
          isVisibleDopDown === true ? "drop-down__container_visible" : ""
        }`}
      >
        {
          //сразу строим компоненты
          groupsWithData.map((item) => {
            return (
              <Group
                key={item.group_id}
                groupName={item.group_name}
                idGroup={item.group_id}
                positionData={item.group_data}
                isOpen={item.group_isOpen}
                handleToggleVisibleGroup={handleToggleVisibleGroup}
              />
            );
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropDown;
```

upd. по `Group`
Встречал подобную проблему, когда делал зависимости имен классов от пропсов.
Попробуйте вообще не рендерить элемент, если `isOpen = false` (см. пример ниже), либо используйте classnames (ссылка выше)

```js
import "./Group.css";
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "../Checkbox/Checkbox";
import Position from "../Position/Position";
import arrow from "../../img/arrow.png";
import uniq from "uniqid";

const Group = ({
  groupName,
  positionData,
  idGroup,
  isOpen,
  handleToggleVisibleGroup,
}) => {
  return (
    <li onClick={() => handleToggleVisibleGroup(idGroup)} className="group">
      <div className="group__header">
        <Checkbox label={groupName} />
        <img className="group__header-img" src={arrow} alt="" />
      </div>
      {
      //если isOpen = false, то не рендерим
      isOpen && (
        <ul className={`group__items-list group__items-list_visible`}>
          {positionData.map((item) => {
            const keyId = uniq();
            return (
              <Position
                id={keyId}
                key={keyId}
                label={item.position_name}
                persons={item.persons}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      )}
    </li>
  );
};

export default Group;
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое! Так действительно работает первоначальное отображение без всяких useState, но все-таки первоначального эффекта я не добился - при клике по Group и вызову ф-ии const handleToggleVisibleGroup = (groupId) => {
        dispatch(toggleVisiblePosition(groupId))
    }
у меня не открываеися сама группа... Т.е. элемент не перерендеривается, когда меняются данные в state. Группа становится открытой только когда я закрываю и открываю снова весь DropDown

Comment: Смотрите в редюсер, у вас, судя по всему, стейт не меняется, т.к. изменение `groupsWithData` будет приводить к ререндеру.

Comment: Он меняется... т.е. изменения вносятся, т.к. после закрытия DropDown и повторного открытия - группа, по которой я кликнул до этого отображается открытой. Она не открывается при клике... вот в чем странность

Comment: компонент `Group` прикрепите

Comment: Прикрепил Group

Comment: Так же добавил то, что выводится в консоли при клике по Group

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: попробовал и не рендерить если isOpen=false и с помощью classnames - поведение не изменилось. Вложенности не открываются

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136250/discussion-between-xydope-and-elarri).